# Replacing unique character with others in android studio

Tags: android, replace, special-characters

I want to replace some character in my string:

```
"google.com\123"
```

I want to replace `"\"` with `"/"` so that my link correct.

```
String google = "google.com\123";
google = google.replace("\", "/");
```

But it doesn't work since the `"\"` character is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
String google = "google.com\123"; google = google.replace("\\", "/");
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

why not try

```
String google = "google.com" + "\" + 123";
```

and then add

```
google = goolge.replace("\", "/");
```

Comment: doesn't work. can not use this "\" to replace other character

Comment: wait my bad, make sure you have both "" around "123"